# Use Advanced filter to copy data in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I would like to filter using auto filter or advanced filter

i have a excel Master sheet with 400K records

I have a list of 31 alpha numeric data

I have to copy records from Master sheet if field "K" has got any of these 31 alpha numeric data

I tried with following.  It did not work. Your help would be appreciated.

```
Sub AAA_MyFilter()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Long
Dim rng2 As Long
Dim rng3 As Long
Dim rng4 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Active")   ' Data
Set ws2 = Worksheets("NYorkPstlCode")   ' Criteria
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Consolidated")   ' Output

rng1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

rng2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


rng3 = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rng4 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To rng4

Set fltrDataField = ws1.Range("J" & i)

For x = 2 To rng2
Set filtrListField = ws2.Range("A" & x)

For y = 2 To rng3


ws1.Range("j" & i).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=ws2.Range("A" & x), _
    CopyToRange:=ws3.Range("A2" & y), _
    Unique:=False

     Next y
    Next x
    Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub **`ProcessWorkSheets()`** copies filtered data from "Active" and "Passive" sheets to "Consolidated"

(if Active.ColK or Passive.ColK contain values from NYorkPstlCode.ColA)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessWorkSheets()
    With Application.ThisWorkbook
        ConsolidatePostalCodes .Worksheets("Active")  'Last row determined by vals in col A
        ConsolidatePostalCodes .Worksheets("Passive") 'Last row determined by vals in col A
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ConsolidatePostalCodes(ByRef wsD As Worksheet)
    Const COL_A = "A"
    Const COL_K = 11
    Dim wsC As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, i As Long, t As Double
    Dim lrD As Long, lrC As Long, lrO As Long, maxRows As Long

    t = Timer
    maxRows = Rows.Count
    With Application.ThisWorkbook
        Set wsC = .Worksheets("NYorkPstlCode")      'Criteria
        Set wsO = .Worksheets("Consolidated")       'Output
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If wsD.AutoFilterMode Then wsD.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    lrD = wsD.Cells(maxRows, COL_A).End(xlUp).Row
    lrC = wsC.Cells(maxRows, COL_A).End(xlUp).Row
    lrO = wsO.Cells(maxRows, COL_A).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To lrC
        With wsD
            With .UsedRange
                .AutoFilter Field:=COL_K, Criteria1:=wsC.Cells(i, COL_A).Value2
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Copy wsO.Cells(lrO, COL_A)
            End With
            lrO = wsO.Cells(maxRows, COL_A).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With
    Next

    wsD.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "#,##0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

Comment: It is wonderful solution. Million Thanks Paul. you have saved me from multiple crash of excel and hours of computer freeze. I am little greedy here... what should I do to copy filtered data from two sheets "Active" and "Passive"?

Comment: @kailash - I'm glad it helped; I made an update for the additional WorkSheet "Passive"

Comment: it is brilliant.  I could not sense the time part of the code  and its effect. but this processed perfectly and fast. I am grateful for this solution.